# Incompatible declaration in drawing a sfml ship

Tags: c++

The beginning of the header file

```
    #include<cmath>
    #include <SFML/Window.hpp>
    #include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
    #include<iostream>
    #include"vector.h"
    #include "ship.h"

    //Constants
    const double PI = 3.14159;
    const double THRUST = 0.005;
    const double TURN_SPEED = 1;

    //constructor
    Ship::Ship(){
    maxLocations.x = 1000;
    maxLocations.y = 1000;
    radius = 5;

    location.x = 0;
    location.y = 0;

    velocity.x = 0;
    velocity.y = 0;

    angleDeg = 0;
```

}

Below is the function that I'm having issues with, it resides in the header file, like the above code block

```
    void Ship::draw(sf::RenderWindow& win) {
    //Initializes the Ship class to an object
    Ship obj;

    // draw ship
    sf::ConvexShape ship;
    ship.setPointCount(3);
    ship.setPoint(0, sf::Vector2f(10, 0));
    ship.setPoint(1, sf::Vector2f(0, 25));
    ship.setPoint(2, sf::Vector2f(20, 25));

    sf::Vector2f midpoint(10,15);
    ship.setOrigin(midpoint);

    ship.setFillColor(sf::Color(0, 0, 0));
    ship.setOutlineThickness(1);
    ship.setOutlineColor(sf::Color(255, 255, 255));

    ship.setPosition(obj.getLocation().x, obj.getLocation().y);
    obj.setAngle(obj.getAngle());
    win.draw(ship);
```

}

The draw() implementation in the source code file

```
    #ifndef SHIP_H
    #define SHIP_H

    #include "vector.h"

    class Ship {
    private: 
    ...

    public:

    //constructor
    Ship();
    ...
    void draw();
     };
     #endif
```

I've never posted here, but read a lot of helpful things here, so I'm giving it a shot. Basically between the definition in the header file and the implementation in the source file I get an error stating

" 1 IntelliSense: declaration is incompatible with "void Ship::draw()" (declared at line 36 of "c:\ship.h") c:\ship.cpp"

I'm using the sfml game engine to just try and draw a ship, so I'm a little more out of my element than usual. 
I hope I've formatted this in a helpful way, let me know if I've just screwed it up for you trying to help me, and thanks in advance, it'll save me a lot of time to get help on this, cause I just don't understand why I keep getting stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Header file has no parameters on draw method declaration.  Method implementation has a parameter.

Comment: That was it. Thanks a bunch friend.